# How to fix the time display at the top of the screen flashing?

Tags: sleep-wake, ios, unlock, iphone

Sometimes when I unlock my iPhone 6s 64Gb with iOS 9.2 the time display at the top of the screen flashes or the whole display at the top of the screen (signal strength time and battery) takes a second to appear. This seems to happen only after not using the phone for more than 30 seconds. Ex. I put the phone on standby, unlock it one minute later. It also seems to happen more often when I use the fingerprint scanner to unlock it, not as much when I enter my passcode, and when I unlock the phone quickly like unlocking from standby with a fingerprint rather than waking the phone up first and then unlocking it. Has anyone else experienced this and does anyone know how to fix it, or is it just a minor bug that will be fixed in 9.3?
-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed the same thing, but *only when there was a notification on the lock screen*.  I'm chalking it up to that, and not worrying about it.  But still interested to learn more if anyone knows anything.

Comment: By the way -- iphone SE iOS 9.3.1

Comment: Wow didn't think anyone would answer this, thanks. Now that you pointed it out I noticed that is what happens with my phone as well. Hopefully Apple knows about this subtle but annoying issue and will fix it in the next update.